# How to filter Cassandra result based on WRITETIME

Tags: cassandra, cql

I would like to get values, whose WRITETIME value is newer than a certain time.  I tried this query, but it fails:

```
SELECT zoom,idx FROM tiles
WHERE zoom=5 AND writetime(tile) > maxTimeuuid('2015-01-01 00:05+0000')
ALLOW FILTERING;
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] 
    message="line 1:68 no viable alternative at input '(' (...and idx > 0 
    and [writetime](...)">
```

For this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tiles (
    zoom int,
    idx int,
    tile blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (zoom, idx)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`WRITETIME` is a function used for displaying the time a specific column was written.  It is not a part of the PRIMARY KEY, nor is it indexed, so it cannot be used in your WHERE clause.  To be able to query by the time a particular *row* (not column) was written, you should add that to your table as an additional column **and** as your first clustering key:

```
CREATE TABLE tilesByLastWritten (
    zoom int,
    idx int,
    tile blob,
    lastwritten timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (zoom, lastwritten, idx)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (lastwritten DESC, idx ASC);
```

Now this query will work:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM tilesByLastWritten 
    WHERE zoom=5 AND lastwritten > mintimeuuid('2015-07-02 08:30:00-0500');

 zoom | lastwritten                          | idx | tile
------+--------------------------------------+-----+------
    5 | 3a439c60-20bf-11e5-b9cb-21b264d4c94d |   1 | null

(1 rows)
```

Notes:

- Don't use the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive.  Basically this tells Cassandra that it's ok to pull all of your table's rows from all of your nodes, and then apply your filters.
- Don't use `COMPACT STORAGE` on table creation.  This was specifically designed for people to convert new CQL3 tables to the legacy Thrift engine storage format.  If you're not doing *specifically that*, then you shouldn't use it.
- I specified the CLUSTERING ORDER in my example to sort the `tiles` table by `lastwritten` in DESCending order.  Usually, timeseries-based applications care about getting the most-recent data, so this usually makes sense.  If this is not the case for you, then the (default) ASCending order should be fine.
- In my example I included `idx` as the last clustering key, mainly for uniqueness.  If you find yourself having to build queries for that column, you may need a different query table (with a re-arranged primary key) to support that.

For more help in this area, give Patrick McFadin's [Getting Started With Timeseries Data Modeling](https://docs.datastax.com/en/tutorials/Time_Series.pdf) a read.

Comment: Thx Bryce!  Most of the time I will be doing queries in the form `SELECT tile FROM tiles WHERE zoom=? AND idx=?` (results in 1 row).  Much more infrequently, I will do "SELECT idx, WRITETIME(tile) FROM tiles WHERE zoom=? AND idx >= ? AND idx < ?` to get a list of all outdated tiles that need to be regenerated. It would have been good to do the filtering on the server.  Should I still add the new column? I expect to have 100s of millions of tiles.

Comment: @Yurik In that case, your original table should serve those queries just fine.  But if you did want to query by the last write time then I would advise creating a separate table (similar to the one I have described above) to support that query.

Comment: It seems that `COMPACT STORAGE` is a good idea if you have a simple table that is not to change over time... It makes things faster and ... more compact (35%). http://blog.librato.com/posts/cassandra-compact-storage